# What variants are unlockable in Towerfall Ascension?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

What sorts of variants can be unlocked while playing Towerfall Ascension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bolt Arrows** (and the corresponding "No Bolt Arrows" variant) are unlockable by unlocking the stage Sunken City.

**Super Bomb Arrows** (and the corresponding "No Super Bomb Arrows" variant) are unlockable by unlocking the stage Towerforge.

**Feather Arrows** (and the corresponding "No Feather Arrows" variant) are unlockable by unlocking the stage Ascension.

**Dark Portals** are unlockable by unlocking the purple archer.

**Gunn Style** is unlockable by going to the credits screen and press Left Right Up Up Down Jump.